# What's the difference between 'open -a TextMate.app' and 'mate'?

Tags: textmate

I've thought that mate is virtually the same as 'open -a TextMate.app', but I guess I'm wrong in this.

As when I run the following command, when there's no hello2.txt, I get this error.

```
open -a TextMate.app hello2.txt
The file /Users/smcho/hello2.txt does not exist.
```

But, it's OK to run mate.

```
mate hello.txt --> opens the text mate.
```

What's the difference between the two?

I even tried

```
open -a TextMate.app --args hello2.txt
```

But this time, TextMate run with the file name 'Untitled', not 'hello2.txt'.

And this code opens the 'hello3.txt' without any problem.

```
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/MacOS/TextMate"     arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello3.txt", nil]];
```

Comment: `mate` is a special executable that comes bundled with TextMate. `open` is a generic executable that comes with Mac OS. They are completely different. Run `man mate` and `man open` to see their differences.

Comment: Also, your question is a better fit for superuser.com.

Comment: @zneak : As I added to the question, when I tried to run the binary inside the bundle of TextMate.app, there's no problem in opening `non-existing file`. So, I guess mate is the binary inside the bundle. But, even though my guess is correct, I don't get it why --args doesn't work with TextMate.app.

Comment: Your guess is probably not correct. Type `which mate` to see where the `mate` executable actually resides. For the rest, I'm not too sure either, but you should ask superuser for software-related questions rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` will open the given file with the default or a specific application.

```
open -a TextMate.app hello2.txt
```

means "Open the file `hello2.txt` using the application TextMate.app".
If there is no `hello2.txt`, there's nothing `open` could open, with or without TextMate.app, hence the error.

```
open -a TextMate.app --args hello2.txt
```

means "open nothing specific in the application TextMate.app (i.e. only open TextMate.app) and pass 'hello2.txt' as additional argument". This is a different kind of argument than the first example. TextMate.app can decide what to do with that additional argument. Apparently it chooses to ignore it.

`mate` is a utility optionally installed by TextMate.

```
mate hello.txt
```

means "I'd like to edit a file called `hello.txt` in TextMate", which is exactly what TextMate will let you do. It's a different utility with different behavior and different purpose, and it seems to better suite what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but I still don't understand why 'launchedTaskWithLaunchPath' works. It indicates that TextMate cares about the parameters (arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello3.txt").